# How to use return statement inside a class in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c#. I have I code block for different textboxes. I decided to create class for this code to use in different windows forms.

here is my windows form code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POS.screens
{
    public partial class sell : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        ConnectionClass cons = new ConnectionClass();
        FillComboBox fcb = new FillComboBox();
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public void PriceTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(QuantityTextBox.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(PriceTextBox.Text))
            {
                TotalTextBox.Text = 0.ToString();
                
            }

            else
            {
                fcb.CheckNumbersOnly(PriceTextBox);

                int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTextBox.Text);
                decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceTextBox.Text);
                decimal Total = Price * Quantity;
                TotalTextBox.Text = Total.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Here is Class Code

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POS
{
    class FillComboBox
    {
        ConnectionClass cons = new ConnectionClass();

        public void CheckNumbersOnly(dynamic TextBoxName)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxName.Text, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?") && (TextBoxName.Text != ""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(TextBoxName.Text);
                return;
            }
            if (!decimal.TryParse(TextBoxName.Text, out decimal PriceValue))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Correct Number");
                TextBoxName.Clear();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine But return statement is not working. If user inserts a letter or incorrect number. Program should show message and stop further working but It does not stop. It shows message and run next statement and give error.

When I use this code directly without creating class It works fine.
I think, my way to use return statement in class is wrong.
I am new learner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using void as a return type means the calling class isn't aware of the result. Also you should separate logic from presentation, CheckNumbersOnly shouldn't be dealing with MessageBox or TextBox. And leave dynamic unless you really need it.

Comment: That `return` only exits the method it is in. Change the return type to `bool`, return either true or false and check that returned value in your event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, a simple one would be for your `CheckNumbersOnly` method to return a boolean.  Probably better to rename it too (for readability), and then in the `PriceTextBox_TextChanged` method, you'd check that the return is true and continue only if it is.

Putting that together:

Validation code:

```cs
public bool NumbersAreValid(string value)
{
   if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?") && (value != ""))
   {
      //Note: this isn't a very good error message, and the above Match 
      // check seems to redo the work of `TryParse` bellow
      MessageBox.Show(value);
      //Let caller know this failed validation
      return false;
   }
   if (!decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal PriceValue))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Correct Number");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Form code:

```cs
public void PriceTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(QuantityTextBox.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(PriceTextBox.Text))
   {
      TotalTextBox.Text = 0.ToString();
   } 
   else 
   {
      //When NumbersAreValid returns false, this if statement ends processing
      if (!fcb.NumbersAreValid(PriceTextBox.Text)) return;

      int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTextBox.Text);
      decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceTextBox.Text);
      decimal Total = Price * Quantity;
      TotalTextBox.Text = Total.ToString();
   }
}
```

There are some other considerations, your `PriceTextBox_TextChanged` method duplicates the efforts of the validation method (by re-parsing the number).. so the validation method could instead return a decimal or throw an exception - the content of the exception would be the message to display in a `MessageBox`.  You'd then need to wrap the validation attempt in a `try {} catch{}` block.  You also seem to use `QuantityTextBox` without any validation - but perhaps that's just for this example.

Comment: I need 1 more favor. 
I want to clear textbox when error occurs. 
I want to add Textbox.Clear() before return false inside class. But it is not working.

Comment: You can combine that stage with checking that the validation passed: `if (!fcb.NumbersAreValid(PriceTextBox.Text)) {PriceTextBox.Clear();return;}`

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Can you please suggest me any book or any tutorials for c# to learn beginner to advance level coding.